# Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1 optional relations per relation removed?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

In Neo4j 2.0.0-M05 i used to do

```
START n=node(*) MATCH n-[r?]-() WHERE ID(n) <> 0 AND ID(n) <> 1 DELETE n, r
```

To delete the entire database except node 0 and 1. Now in Noe4j 2.0.0-RC1 I can not use the question mark anymore. But instead i have to use the OPTIONAL keyword like this:

```
START n=node(*) OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-() WHERE ID(n) <> 0 AND ID(n) <> 1 DELETE n, r
```

## Problem 1

It matches node 1 (node 0 was not present in the database at the moment of the query)

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ START n=node(*) OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-() WHERE ID(n) <> 1 RETURN n, r;
+--------------------+
| n         | r      |
+--------------------+
| Node[1]{} | <null> |
+--------------------+
```

This is of course not a problem only for this one query, but throughout the application where I need to use similar queries.

## Problem 2

As it looks to me this introduced a serious design flaw. Maybe my reasoning is off here, and also I could not test it yet because of Problem 1. But the `OPTIONAL` keyword severely limits the possibilities to make queries. As written in the announcement here http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/11/neo4j-200-rc1-final-preparations.html `OPTIONAL` can be compared to an `OUTER JOIN`. To keep up with this anology hopping from node to node would be like adding an extra join.

So before

```
MATCH (a)-[x]-(b)-[y?]-(c) RETURN a, b, c
```

Would be like doing

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM ??
INNER JOIN x ON ??
LEFT OUTER JOIN y ON ??
```

(question marks in place because cypher does not translate to SQL)
But not with the OPTIONAL keyword either you make all the joins `OUTER JOIN` or all the joins `INNER JOIN` (without the optional keyword). My application doesn't work without mixed inner/outer join queries. To me it's very basic to make the relational optional *PER HOP*. So either I have to stay at M06 (the latest version to support the question mark) or try another database.

Signed,

Desperate developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide some sample data and expected results. I'm pretty sure your two queries can be rewritten with optional match as below.

The reason your WHERE clause acts weirdly, is because the WHERE directly following the OPTIONAL MATCH only gets run when the OPTIONAL MATCH matches something, as a filter for that OPTIONAL MATCH. So in this case, you're finding n (id = 1), it's not matching n-[r]-(), since n doesn't have a relationship, and then it's returning n. You need to filter your n first, although I recommend using just MATCH instead of START (in this case it doesn't matter, but usually MATCH is better).

For your #1, you need to do this query instead:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE ID(n) <> 1   
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-() 
RETURN n, r;
```

For your #2:

```
MATCH (a)-[x]-(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[y]-(c)
RETURN a, b, c // c will be null if it doesn't exist
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everything was solved with your queries. Faith has been restored! Things start to match sense again :) thank you.

Comment: No problem. I just posted this: http://wes.skeweredrook.com/cypher-2-0-optional-match/